Use babel language selector in biblatex/biber URL
In an English document with occasional Thai words, I've been able to use babel's Thai language selector to good effect, including in citations, but not in URL citations (which are unicode-encoded thanks to this solution).
Minimal example:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inreference{Wikipedia::Vimanmek,
    lista    = {{\textthai{พระที่นั่งวิมานเมฆ} \mkbibbrackets{Vimanmek Mansion}}},
    title    = {Wikipedia},
    entrysubtype = {online},
    url      = {https://th.wikipedia.org/wiki/พระที่นั่งวิมานเมฆ},
    % url      = {\textthai{https://th.wikipedia.org/wiki/พระที่นั่งวิมานเมฆ}}, % doesn't work
    % url      = {https://th.wikipedia.org/wiki/\textthai{พระที่นั่งวิมานเมฆ}}, % doesn't work
    userd    = {last edited},
    urldate     = {2023-03-10T14:17:00},
}

@inreference{Wikipedia::Sirindhorn,
    lista    = {{\textthai{สมเด็จพระกนิษฐาธิราชเจ้า กรมสมเด็จพระเทพรัตนราชสุดาฯ สยามบรมราชกุมารี} \mkbibbrackets{Princess Sirindhorn}}},
    title    = {Wikipedia},
    entrysubtype = {online},
    url      = {https://th.wikipedia.org/wiki/สมเด็จพระกนิษฐาธิราชเจ้า_กรมสมเด็จพระเทพรัตนราชสุดาฯ_สยามบรมราชกุมารี},
    urldate  = {2024-04-02T08:29:00},
    userd    = {last edited},
}

\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \robustify

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
\babelprovide[import]{thai}
\babeltags{thai = thai}
\robustify\textthai

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \href{#1}{\nolinkurl{\thefield{urlraw}}}}

\begin{document}

Hello\autocite{Wikipedia::Vimanmek} World\autocite{Wikipedia::Sirindhorn}.

\end{document}

In the first example, the title in quotation marks is displayed correctly, but not the URL, whose diacritics are out of place. The second example's URL might benefit from Thai-aware wrapping.

